# Prove formula for $n^{th}$ derivative

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing, binomial-theorem

I have this math question. That I am stuck on.

> If $f$ is a function, let $Df$ be its derivative.  For $n\in
>  \mathbb{Z}^+$ let $$ f^{(n)} = \underbrace{D \cdots D }_{n\mathrm{\
>  times}} f $$ be the $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative of $f$.  In this
>    notation the usual product rule from calculus  says that   $$
>  (fg)^{(1)} = fg^{(1)} + f^{(1)} g. $$ Using the product rule, prove
>    the formula for the $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative of a product  $$
>  (fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)}. $$ (Hint: 
>    The proof in here is similar to the proof of the Binomial Theorem.)

I can see that for example is $n=2$ the equation becomes $\binom{2}{0}f^{2}+\binom{2}{1}f^{1}g^1+\binom{2}{2}g^2=f^2+2fg+g^2$. I'm not sure how to prove this though. Thanks.

Comment: You can prove it by induction.

Comment: Try a proof by induction. You already know it holds for $n=1,2$; now see if you can show that the statement is true for $n+1$, given that it holds for $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Induction will come down to proving that ...

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\left (  f^{(n-k+1)} g^{(k)} + f^{(n-k)} g^{(k+1)}   \right)= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} f^{(n+1-k)} g^{(k)}.$$

Comment: I get the assumption $(fg)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{n-k}g^k$... but how do you relate $(fg)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}f^{n+1-k}g^k$ to it?

Comment: differentiate $(fg)^{(n)}$ to get the l.h.s. of the above equation

Comment: I'm still not understanding how differentiating it will get you $f^{(n-k+1)}g^{(k)}+f^{(n-k)}g^{(k+1)}$

Comment: use the product rule on $f^{(n-k)}g^{(k)}$

Comment: Doesn't it become $(n-k)f^{(n-k-1)}g^k+kg^{(k-1)}f^{(n-k)}$?

Comment: $f^{(n)}$ means the $n^{th}$ derivative , the $n$ is in no way an exponent and should always be written complete with brackets.

Comment: So, then why do you add 1 to the exponent? $f^{(n-k+1)}$?

Comment: it is not an exponent .  the superscript increases by one because $Df^{(n)} \equiv f^{(n+1)}$